# RegEx Repeating Capture Group

Tags: python, regex

I have the following data:

```
 User ID              Name                                                         Last Activity Date     
 -------------------- ------------------------------------------------------------ -----------------------
UserID1               UserName1                                                    2016-05-31
UserID2               UserName2                                                    2016-05-31
UserID3               UserName3                                                    2016-05-31
...
```

What is the best way to use RegEx to capture all the UserIDs, Names, and Activity Dates?

I currently have `User ID\s+Name\s+Last Activity Date\s+[- \s]+(.*?)\s+(.*?)\s{6,}(.*)\s` and this is able to capture the first line but how can I repeat this to get all the other lines?

Comment: I am using Python for this

Comment: @Bijan What made you pick regex as the tool for this task? Surely there are others more suitable.

Comment: See if it help: http://regexr.com/3dhpo

Comment: @Biffen: What would be a better way?

Comment: @Bijan I'm no Python expert, but there should be a module for reading tabular data. If not, you should at least read it line by line and split the cells by their offsets.

Comment: Clearly, read the file line by line and split.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please have a look at the regex in the link: https://regex101.com/r/gN2cH2/2
The python code generated from the link is. This regex captures all the USerIDs, names , activity dates except the heading row.

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'((UserID[0-9])\s+(UserName[0-9]+)\s+([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}))')
test_str = u" User ID              Name                                                         Last Activity Date     \n -------------------- ------------------------------------------------------------ -----------------------\nUserID1               UserName1                                                    2016-05-31\nUserID2               UserName2                                                    2016-05-31\nUserID3               UserName3                                                    2016-05-31"

re.findall(p, test_str)
```

You can find the values of UserID's , names and capturing and last activity using capturing groups of paranthesis.